# Android data binding? issue after calling recreate activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

First of all, I am not sure if this is a data binding issue, that is just a guess. Please ignore it. Problem is as follows:

In my `MainActivity.kt`, I use DataBinding as follows:

```
class MainActivity: BaseActivity(){
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        ...

        binding.someText.text = "A text"
    }
    ...
}
```

`BaseActivity.kt`, extends `AppCompatActivity()`. Now, upon clicking on a button, which changes user locale (and language of the app), I recreate the activity by calling `recreate()` in the `MainActivity.kt`. And the user locale changes, language of the app changes, so no problem here.

However, after the recreation, value of the `someText` becomes an empty string even though the `onCreate` method is called and the value is set (I observed this via debugging). My question is what could cause the value of `someText` to be an empty string exactly, why it is not set?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution, in case someone else had the same problem.

Inside my `onCreate()` method, I simply run `post()` method on my main layout with an action that loads the my data on the UI. In this way, I simply made sure that the data is loaded after the outside most view is created.